# Is it possible to share/download AWS launch templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to share an [AWS launch template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/LaunchTemplates.html) with another account, either directly or download and share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to share or export Launch Templates.

However, you can make an API call to extract the configuration of a Launch Template (eg in Python use [`describe_launch_template_versions()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_launch_template_versions).

You can then programmatically create a new Launch Template in a different account.